# assign unique ID to each unique value in group after pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame as following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b','c','c','d','e','a','h','i','a'],'col2':['3:00','3:00','4:00','4:00','3:00','5:00','5:00','3:00','3:00','2:00']})

df
Out[83]: 
  col1  col2
0    a  3:00
1    b  3:00
2    c  4:00
3    c  4:00
4    d  3:00
5    e  5:00
6    a  5:00
7    h  3:00
8    i  3:00
9    a  2:00
```

What I'd like to do is groupby 'col1' and assign a unique ID to different values in col2 as following:

```
col1  col2  ID
 a    2:00   0
 a    3:00   1
 a    5:00   2
 b    3:00   0
 c    4:00   0
 c    4:00   0
 ...
```

I tried to use pd.Categorical but can't quite get to where I wanted to be.

Answer (score 14):

we can use [pd.factorize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) method:

```
In [170]: df['ID'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])

In [171]: df
Out[171]:
  col1  col2  ID
0    a  3:00   0
1    b  3:00   0
2    c  4:00   0
3    c  4:00   0
4    d  3:00   0
5    e  5:00   0
6    a  5:00   1
7    h  3:00   0
8    i  3:00   0
9    a  2:00   2
```

Comment: @jezrael, thank you! BTW: I've stopped checking & answering Pandas questions... ;-)

Comment: @jezrael, i want to learn something new - machine learning, deep learning, etc.

Comment: @MaxU  Ah, sorry, there were a bunch of similar Q&As that were not linked and I went overboard linking this.  Deleted all my comments.  Good luck with ML!